# How to restore deleted unversioned files in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have just deleted all my unversioned files in mercurial thinking they were all .origs

It turns out my test classes were in there which i had been working on. Is it possible to restore these in anyway?

I am guessing the answer is no, I hope the answer is yes!

Comment: Maybe your filesystem supports some sort of undelete operation; otherwise I don't think so. Mercurial can't help you since it didn't know about the files yet.

Comment: For future reference: you can get a list of unversioned files via `hg st` (they're prefixed with `?`).  It's usually a good idea to do this before running `hg purge`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry I'm afraid you can't. If you had committed them, you could have used `hg revert` to restore the files to their checkout state. But as Mercurial has never heard of these files, it cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am the luckiest guy alive!

Eclipse still had the Emma coverage statistics open, so if i right click the file in there, then replace from history i get the window with the code in it , its about an hour older but so much better than starting again!

Comment: For future: start to use hg commit --amend. Thus commit early and often

Comment: Very glad that you could recover your files! :)